# This piece of python code hung up my whole system , Does anybody have a clue?

Tags: python-3.x, vagrant, freebsd, opensuse

My host system is OpenSuse 13.2 and i am running FreeBsd 10.1 on vagrant

when i ran following code on Freebsd 10.1 running on vagrant , not only freebsd but the host system hung up and i had to manually press power button to shutdown .

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
import os,subprocess
subprocess.Popen("cd /usr/local/ && sh",shell=True)
```

on freebsd output of

> **$ ps $$**

is

> PID TT  STAT    TIME COMMAND
>
> 900  0  Ss   0:00.47 -sh (sh)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by opening a shell from Python? Use the appropriate commands from for example `os` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly doubt, the hang was due to the script. It would not hang the OS, and it most certainly would not hang the host.

I just ran this "script" here without any ill-effects. Most likely you had a problem with your vagrant-host (hardware error?), which happened to coincide with you running the script.

Have you tried it again -- after the host came back?